# Xamarin web reference can not reachable

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

I couldn't figure out the problem I was having in Xamarin. I share the screenshot below.

I've added Web Reference for Android and iOs. There is no problem in my previous projects. But I can't reach the web reference.

[image]

Comment: You are using a .NetStd/PCL library for the magazine project and thus do not have access to the Android/iOS namespaces (look at your `#if` blocks, both the iOS and Android sections are greyed out. If you want to do it that way, the magazine project needs to be a "Shared Project", not a library.

Comment: Thank you. This was fixed my problem.